# Looping througt ID's from database table in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde

I am new to PDI and want to achieve looping. So the scenario goes like this...

I have a URL like `{store}/admin/orders/{orderID}/metafields.json`, So I have orderIDs in the table but I want to iteratively change the orderID in the URL.

For Example:

```
**OrderID** [1,2,3,.....n]

{store}/admin/orders/**1**/metafields.json

{store}/admin/orders/**2**/metafields.json

{store}/admin/orders/**3**/metafields.json
.

.

.

.

{store}/admin/orders/**n**/metafields.json
```

I tried to do it via variables but no success. It only returns the 1st orderID, not the rest.

The current setup is

```
 **Transformation 1** ---> **table input** (orderIDs) --> **setVariables** (setting orderID as variable)

**Transforamtion 2** ---> **getVariables** (orderIDs) --> **textoutput** (for testing)

**job 1** ---> **start** -->  **Transformation 1** (with **execute for every input row** option checked) --> **Transformation 2** --> **success**
```

any alternative will be highly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are thinking for loop, is not correct in PDI. I have prepared a solution for you [Loop](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-x9GIRa8n9_zu9bJ98q4N0up6To4rj1p?usp=sharing), you can get help from here.

Please let me know if you need anything else.
Note: you need to run MainJob2.kjb.

Also, I have uploaded the output log file , after I run this job.

Comment: Thank you so much @Runa. Helps alot.. I tried it and it works. Although i am still trying to understand it.. But Thanks for taking out time and configuring the whole thing.

Comment: In pdi, you need to use a job for creating loop. getorderid transformation send 1 by 1 row to the looporderid job. And from looporderid job, i call 2nd transformation prepareurl transformation.

Comment: GetOrderid.ktr transformation send 1 by 1 row because, if you double click on jobExecutor step, you will see in row grouping section, i mentioned ""Number of rows to send to transformation" "=1.